# Alternative to Google Hangouts for making free VoIP calls?

Tags: android, voip

Is there an Android alternative to Google Hangouts for making free VoIP calls?

Only outgoing calling is needed.  An incoming number would be a nice bonus, but certainly is not a requirement.

The app itself can be paid, but the calling must be free.

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-apps-voip-sip-calls-wi-fi-calling-internet-calling-87396/

Comment: [A bunch of](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_cheapcall#group_72). But whether calling is free doesn't depend on the app – it depends on the VoIP provider you're using. Usually calls to other VoIP members (at least of the same provider) are free – but as soon you're leaving off towards landline/mobile there are costs.